# React validation using Material UI's TextField components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, material-ui, input-field

I have been researching this for an hour now, and doesnt seem like there is  much examples on this on the internet. I am trying to validate the input fields so that  all fields are filled, otherwise there will be an error. Amount of characters doesnt matter, just need to fill the inputs.

So here is my state object

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      firstName: '',
      lastName: '',
      ...,
    
    };
  }
```

And here are the material ui textfields

```
<TextField
                className={classes.formInput}
                name="firstName"
                onChange={e => this.handleChange(e.target.value)}
                required
                id=""
                type="text"
                InputLabelProps={{
                  shrink: true,
                }}
                error={!firstName}
                helperText="Name is required"
                label="First Name"
                variant="standard" />
              <TextField
                className={classes.formInput}
                name="lastName"
                onChange={e => this.handleChange(e.target.value)}
                required
                id=""
                type="text"
                InputLabelProps={{
                  shrink: true,
                }}
                label="Last Name"
                variant="standard" />
```

And here is the onchange handler

```
   handleChange = (e) => {
     this.setState({
       [e.target.name]: e.target.value
     });
   }
```

Comment: Are you just trying to check that these fields are filled out before a 'submit' button is pressed?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the comment! The idea is that when they press the submit button, that is when it will check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely that you want to add this validation only after user trying to submit the form. Then, you should create a new state for `formError` and add it to your submit function condition which will check that if your inputs are empty then set state of `formError` to true. After that, your expression for input error state will look like:

`error={formError && firstName.length === 0}`

You will get a nice user experience when your inputs will be highlighted with red only when there was an attempt to submit a form with empty inputs.

Answer (score 0):

When the user is submitting the form, since all you want to do is validate that *something* is filled into the firstName and lastName fields, you can check this with either:

```
this.state.field !== '' //returns true if it's filled in
```

or

```
this.state.field.length > 0 //returns true if it's filled in
```

in whatever 'handleSubmit' function you create, you can call a seperate function to validate all your fields. That validating function can look like this:

```
// returns 'true' if fields filled out, and 'false' if not 
validateForm = () => {
  if (this.state.firstName === '' || this.state.lastName === '') {
    //set error message: 'Please fill out all fields')
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```